# Google Maps info Bubble With Font Awesome Icons and bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, google-maps, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am attempting to customize links int a Google Maps info-bubble with Bootstrap and font awesome Icons.

I was able to use a list-group from bootstrap for my links in the info bubble successfully, but when I tried to add a font awesome Icon to the link it just does not show up.

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8iaZF-iFNk" target="_blank" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"> <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>&nbsp;Hiking 42 Miles along Michigan's Lake Superior (Adventure Archive)</a>
```

I followed the code on this link here: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/

But when I test on my site the font awesome icon doesn't show up like in the example I followed.

[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong....

Comment: If you are using `FontAwesome v4.7.0` then you can't use `fab` class because of this is belong to `FontAwesome v5` so you need to use `fa fa-youtube` instead of `fab fa-youtube`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you gotten the Font Awesome CDN in the `<head>` tags of your file as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`? I don't know if you have issues with other icons in your website, but without that CDN, you may not be able to get your icons to show up! See Font Awesome's [Troubleshooting Page](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/troubleshooting).

What's your code so far? Do you have a parent `<div class="list-group">` above your anchor tag to match the class attributes of your `list-group-item list-group-item-action` anchor tag (but this may just be hierarchy issue, not the cause of your Font Awesome icons not showing up)? Still, check out [this article](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/) by Bootstrap, under "Links and Buttons" header. Play around with it!

Comment: Yep my link wasn't there... I had it in my mobile application but not my website, got lost in the code

Comment: Ahh, yes! Glad you found the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You are follow **`FontAwesome v4.7.0`** then you can't use **`fab`** class because of this is belong to `FontAwesome v5+`. So you just need to replace `fab fa-youtube` to **`fa fa-youtube`**.

```js
function initMap() {
  var lakeShore = {lat: 47.7231, lng: 86.9407};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: lakeShore
  });

  var contentString = `<h6>Lake Shore Trail</h6>
   <div class="list-group">
     <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8iaZF-iFNk" target="_blank" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>&nbsp; Hiking 42 Miles along Michigan's Lake Superior (Adventure Archive)</a>
   </div>`;

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
    // maxWidth: 320
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: lakeShore,
    map: map,
    title: 'Lake Shore Trail'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
</script>
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check either you font awesome link `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">` is working or not as i can see one ERROR in you console window